# MahApps Window maximizing doesn't work when AllowsTransparency set to true

Tags: wpf, transparency, mahapps.metro, maximize

I have experienced a bit a weird behavior of the MahApps Window when I set the `AllowsTransparency` to true. What I am doing is to set the Opacity of the whole window to 0.4 when the mouse leaves the window. When the mouse returns to the window area, the opacity is set back to a value of 1.0.

This works fine unless I want to maximize the MahApps window. It doesn't maximize, but makes a weird blue rectangle around half of the screen, and the window remains the same size as before (The window is resizable... and without the `AllowsTransparency` (in code, after InitializeComponent) everything works fine).

I have uploaded a short .gif to show what I mean:
[image: Gif, which shows the problem]

I set the opacity with following xaml:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.4" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

I hope anyone knows a solution for this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Ramon

Comment: Further information:
When I start the app and maximize immediately, then the window just changes it's location to (0,0) but doesn't resize to full size. The blue rectangle doesn't appear either. This rectangle apears only when I pull the window first on any side of the screen to use half of the screen (see .gif, like WIN+Left/Right)

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? Having the same problem now...

Comment: @kirill-osenkov
No I didn't, but it seems, that a few others have the same issue... I opened an Issue on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2483)) and it seems that it could be a bug in MahApps
you should follow the movements on GitHub, although there haven't been any in the few past months